# Why is the kernel using the default block driver instead of my driver's code?

Tags: linux, kernel, block-device

I wrote a block driver program which creates a dummy block device (`sbd0`). I registered all device operations for that block device: (Refer to `include/linux/blkdev.h` in 2.6.32 kernel source)

```
static struct block_device_operations sbd_ops = {
    .owner           = THIS_MODULE,
    .open            = sbd_open,
    .release         = sbd_close,
    .ioctl           = sbd_ioctl,
    .getgeo          = sbd_getgeo,
    .locked_ioctl    = sbd_locked_ioctl,
    .compat_ioctl    = sbd_compat_ioctl,
    .direct_access   = sbd_direct_access,
    .media_changed   = sbd_media_changed,
    .revalidate_disk = sbd_revalidate_disk
};
```

I compiled the driver program. I inserted the module and `/dev/sbd0` was created. Now I want to test my driver code. So I wrote an application as below.

```
fd = open("/dev/sbd0", O_RDONLY); 
retval = ioctl(fd, BLKBSZGET, &blksz); //trying to get logical block size
```

Output is :`4096`

I wondered: I didn't implement ioctl for `BLKBSZGET`. It didn't invoke my `sbd_ioctl`, instead it used the default driver and gave me the result. For `open`, `close` calls it executed `sbd_open` and `sbd_close` (that I implemented). And then I tried:

```
retval = ioctl(fd, HDIO_GETGEO, &geoinfo);
```

It invoked `sbd_getgeo` but I thought it would invoke `sbd_ioctl`.

Here are my questions:

1. I implemented a driver and created a device. If I perform any operation on that device, it has to invoke my driver application. But how does it use a few of my driver functions and few default driver functions?
2. `ioctl(fd, HDIO_GETGEO, ..)` didn't invoke `.ioctl` call, but it invoked `.getgeo`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ioctl` dispatching is handled by the `blkdev_ioctl` function, which will process some of the ioctls directly, without calling into your driver's specific routine.

For `HDIO_GETGEO`, it calls your driver's `getgeo` function directly (from kernel 3.13.6, doesn't appear to have changed much since 2.6.32):

```
[...]
/*
 * We need to set the startsect first, the driver may
 * want to override it.
 */
memset(&geo, 0, sizeof(geo));
geo.start = get_start_sect(bdev);
ret = disk->fops->getgeo(bdev, &geo); /* <- here */
[...]
```

For `BLKBSZGET`, it calls `block_size(bdev))`, which simply returns `bdev->bd_block_size`.

You'll find `blkdev_ioctl` in `block/ioctl.c` if you need to know what happens for other ioctls.

Comment: you mean, first `ioctl` handled by `blkdev_ioctl`. So directly few `ioctl` operations handled by `blkdev_ioctl` and remaining will handled by my driver functions?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: I saw the definition of `blkdev_ioctl`. really good and very clear. Now I want to see how `ioctl` calling `blkdev_ioctl`. I want to see source file. In which file I get this?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, there's no `block/ioctl.h` in 3.13 either. The route from userspace ioctl call down to that function is a bit complex. It starts from the syscall interface (`fs/ioctl.c`, `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(ioctl, ...`) then goes down chasing pointers in the VFS structures from the file down to the appropriate driver.